# How to change nopcommerce page title to my one web site name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I want to change each and every page in  nopcommerce web site page title to my one web site name.

How can I do it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in admin menu

Configuration -> Global settings -> store name

In version 2.6 and higher:

Configuration -> Settings -> General and Miscellaneous

Comment: In Admin menu -> Configuration , there is no Global Setting...How can I access it??

Comment: What version of nopcommerce are you on?  In the version I have its there.

Comment: Thanks. I found 

Configuration -> Settings -> General and Miscellaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Change title from "your store":

- Login as Administrator
- Go to Configuration->Settings->General and miscellaneous Settings
- Click on Tab SEO settings
- change Default Title